Saving figure in matplotlib
I have created a figure using matplotlib. Im using the following lines of code to save the figure in pdf format:
fig.tight_layout()

plt.savefig("my plot.pdf", format="pdf", bbox_inches="tight")

plt.show()

The original plot has four subplots, arranged in a 2x2 way. The output pdf file is not having the axes labels for the column 1 plots, it is cutting these labels. Im able to get these labels in the jupyter notebook but in the output pdf files they are missing. please suggest how to fix this issue.
I have tried the following lines of code:
fig.tight_layout()

plt.savefig("my plot.pdf", format="pdf", bbox_inches="tight")

plt.show()

but it is not generating the desired output. I want help in generating the plots in a pdf file without any extra whitespace (so, the "tight" option is important for me) and all axes labels intact.

If you're setting fig.tight_layout() you shouldn't need the bbox_inches="tight" in the savefig call. Also try saving from the fig object directly, e.g., fig.savefig("myplot.pdf").
